# How to Proguard an android project and its modules and libs?

Tags: android, android-studio, module, proguard, libs

I am using Android Studio,  my application uses many modules and libs
Is it possible to proguard all modules , libs and the application ? Or I can do it only for the app ?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable Proguard for the app module, that is the module that includes the others, everything will be obfuscated.

To test it:

- create a new project
- add it a new module, let's call it lib
- add some code to the lib, use this code in the app
- enable Proguard for the app, not for the lib
- in Android Studio:

  - Build -> Clean
  - Build -> Build apk
  - Build -> Analyze apk

You should see that all the code is obfuscated, lib and app.